# Самоучитель для начинающих

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! Посоветуйте какой-нибудь самоучитель для начинающих по JavaScript, а то я только начинаю, и ничего в этом не понимаю. Вчера прочёл самоучитель от Джо Бернса, и Эндри Грауни, но мало что понял.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй [W3Schools JavaScript Reference](http://w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp). Там все с примерами, и можно похимичить самостоятельно. Плюс справка по DOM. Не совсем для начинающих, но очень полезно и доступно

Answer (score 3):

Javascript the definitive guide - точно уж не для начинающего. Читать практически 200 страниц без примеров и без особо понимания, о чём читаешь, - это вряд ли будет способствовать обучению.

Я читал "Раскрытие тайн Javascript", "Javascript.Подробное руководство" (правда эта книга больше по jQuery первоначальное знакомство).

От себя могу посоветовать так: начните с минимума, читая простые книги для чайников, а потом уже для более лучшего закрепления и глубоко понимания материала беритесь за книгу, упомянутую первой.

Answer (score 3):

Я угорел по [javascript гарден](http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/). Быстро и по делу.

Answer (score 2):

Могу порекомендовать отличный русскоязычный ресурс по современному браузерному JavaScript - [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru). Есть [учебник](http://javascript.ru/tutorial) для начинающих. Есть [справочник](http://javascript.ru/manual) по базовым элементам языка (объекты, глобальные методы, свойства, конструкции языка). Примеры кликабельные. Есть [блоги](http://javascript.ru/manual) пользователей сообщества.

Однозначно, достоин того, чтобы держать его у себя в закладках.

Answer (score 2):

Есть удобный сайтец [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) позволяющий вживую поиграться с фрагментами JS кода и посмотреть как они работают.

Comment: слово консоль вам о чем-то говорит? :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript the definitive guide - желательно последнее издание (6-е).

Answer (score 1):

Курс лекций на [intuit.ru](http://www.intuit.ru/department/internet/js/class/free/status/).

Answer (score 1):

Неее, вот то, что нужно. Скачал курс лекций, поглядел за пару раз и практически все понял и узнал, теперь только практика: [видеокурс по JavaScript](http://www.sdelaysite.com/javascript/javascript-video-1).
Кстати, там еще много разный интересных уроков есть.

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже говорил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44594/javascript-c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-js?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=148072#148072)

Для меня лучшая книга:

```
Beginning JavaScript Paul Wilton Jeremy McPeak Third Edition
```

От издательства Wrox

, у меня перевод этой книги

```
Пол Вилтон Джереми МакПик Java Script Руководство программиста
```

от издательства Питер.
У меня эта книга. Я вам её очень советую и (особенно для дизайна) это самый лучший учебник imho