# Учебник по JavaScript

Tags: javascript, книги

Добрый день.

Появилась необходимость узнать JavaScript лучше, чем alert("Hello World!"), подскажите книгу по JavaScript, которая Вам кажется наиболее познавательной и информативной (на русском).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Самоучитель для начинающих](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18105/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Самоучитель для начинающих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18105/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85) - угадал?