# C чего начать изучение JS?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Я новенький, но действительно хочу заняться этим делом. Я выбрал язык JS потому что для него очень легко найти применение и также легко связать с веб дизайном. Недавно скачал книгу с носорожком на обложке по JS, также немного помогал друг. Но сейчас друг не может этого делать и поэтому у меня вопрос: есть ли какие-нибудь достаточно легкие и простые в освоении уроки? Желательно, чтоб они были с примерами и детальными описаниями всего. Я действительно готов заняться изучением по-полной, поэтому кидайте всё (ну только хорошее, конечно же), что у вас есть. Другие языки не предлагать. Носорожек написан на слишком научном языке и с какой-то стремной систематизацией. В общем, это всё. Спасибо заранее. Жду ответов!

Comment: Носорожик это ИМХО лучшая книга по JavaScript, так-же замечательный справочник... Не думайте что изучение языка программирования это быстро и легко...<br>
Если хотите легких путей то качайте себе видеокурсы Попова например, но предупреждаю сразу - если хотите именно изучить JS а не пройтись понемногу по всему абы как - читайте носорога ^^<br>
Не обязательно в день по 100 страниц асиливать, не спешите, всеравно вы потом не раз еще будете возвращатся к уже "пройденому" материалу т.к. всего сразу не выучишь

Comment: Тоесть по твоему для php не найти применение ?) Нууу если ты имел дело с каким нибудь простым языком то хватай справочник и учи функции и методы...Так как он относительно лёгкий в синтаксе.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я и не хочу легких путей. Я скорее хочу легкого и доступного в сложном. Вот мой выше упомянутый друг помог мне постепенно узнать, что такое переменные, массивы, функции. Но напрягать друга не особо хочется да и неудобно как-то. В носороге очень много информации и не особо понятные примеры (читал на электронной книге, может поэтому). А может ещё есть варианты?

Comment: Fatahan, нет, я же не написал, что это единственный такой язык. Просто, насколько я понял, JS позволяет делать достаточно интересные вещи. Поэтому мне он и понравился!

Comment: <small>на C++ можно делать вещи поинтереснее ^^</small>

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаком со строением разных языков. Но люблю веб хостинг. До этого работал на шаблонах типа укоза и изучал немного строение. Но в основном занимался графическим изменением и почти не касался структуры. А вот сейчас вместе с другом начали изучать (не с тем, который мне помогал. Условно назовем х1- друг, который про и х2- друг, с которым начали). В общем с х2 начали изучать, но он раньше уже имел более тесный контакт с программированием. х1 нам немного обьяснил, но он слишком часто этого делать не может. Поэтому и прошу!

Comment: :) Лучше php учи :D А потом уже по чуть чуть до JavaScript и до AJAX а потом и до тюрьмы за взлом сервера пентагона недалеко :D

Comment: Можно и на курсах http://www.specialist.ru/course/oprveb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Друг мой, все элементарно, качай сразу книг 20 ( как я и сделал) . Плюс прикупил еще 3 за нормальные деньги. Если че-то не соображал в одной книге - переходил на другую. С течением времени - блин!- все удалось! Но для этого нужны не протухший мозг и желание программировать. А то, что тебе говорят про php - чушь. Веб-программист должен знать как минимум яваскрипт и пхп. Потому что js - язык сценариев, а пхп - серверный язык и исполняется только на стороне сервера )) Вперед!

Comment: А я php не знаю. Только `Java`. А программисты чисто на `html`-`javaScript` тоже нужны. И освоить `JavaScript` на очень высоком уровне - очень хорошо. Но вот только надо же знать, каким образом происходит клиент-серверное взаимодействие.

Comment: спасибо, действительно хороший ответ. Только вот хотел бы узнать, откуда вы качали книги. И если остались ссылки, буду очень вам признателен. ПХП планирую изучать, но после!

Comment: Важней програмисты на XML и AJAX Если так рассуждать :)

Comment: AJAX - это случайно не JavaScript??? А XML, по-моему, - это как бремя для всех программистов.

Comment: AJAX Это совместное использование ЯвыСкрипта и ХМЛ. "Бремя" в вашем понимании что то вроде "плохо"? Ну тогда я бессилен...Даже доктора бессильны :)<br/> <br/> 
ps. И не путай *Java* и *JavaScript* (А точнее *ECMAScript* =) )

Comment: Ну, я ненавижу XML. И бремя - как ноша, которую несут все программисты. Одна из технологий, без которой много вещей не обходится. А вот по поводу AJAX, так то, что вы ответили - это не все. тут (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) подробнее.

Comment: Всё правильно кроме "Ненавижу" и "Бремя". Ненавидить его - Это тоже самое что ненавидеть к примеру: Ассемблер или С\С++ - Без них тоже многие вещи не обходяться.

Comment: Вот без Ассемблера, С/С++, PHP и много другого, я обхожусь прекрасно. Даже не вспоминаю о них. На счет   
`"И не путай Java и JavaScript (А точнее ECMAScript =) )"`

О_о оказывается есть между ними разница!!! О_ох-ох!

Comment: Антон Мухин - ПрИкИнЬ СаМ В ШоКе! Между ними кроме 4 букв и чуть похожего синтаксиса разница огромная.<br><br>
@Vendetta8247 - Ты как раз на таком форуме...Выкладывай что тебе надо и будем помогать. :)

Comment: @Fatahan - пока мне бы получить хотя бы какой-то багаж знаний :) Если я придумаю что-то, что не знаю, как реализовать, я отпишу.

Comment: "js - язык сценариев, а пхп - серверный язык" 

ога, огурец это овощь, но самолет летает

Comment: > Веб-программист должен знать как минимум яваскрипт и пхп

Я веб-программист, но пхп не знаю.

Comment: @Vladimir VG - ппц я вам завидую =(

Лучше бы я и не знал его :D

Comment: Все же 20 книг перечитывать - это перебор, ИМХО)

Answer (score 4):

Я тоже недавно начал изучать JavaScript по "Носорогу". Книга то что надо, также использую оригинал на английском языке. Также есть очень хороший учебник на сайте Mozilla:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript/guide. Если английский вызывает трудности, то лучше сменить профессию, т.к. для программиста он должен быть вторым родным, ИМХО.

С практикой немного сложнее, но дорогу осилит идущий

Answer (score 2):

Книга с носорогом - крутая книга. И хорошая в изучении. Хочется не по научному,- не та профессия. Лучшее изучение - практика. Когда что-то надо и не знаешь, лезешь в книгу. Через некоторое время, после самостоятельного решения некоторого количества задач, будете шире мыслить и осваивать более отдаленные высоты. И вообще, быстрее всего научитесь, когда возьмете реальный проект за деньги, и начнете стараться выполнить его в срок, как угодно. В общем, попу рвать. Тогда много нового узнаете. И из книги, и из форумов и вообще, откуда угодно. Может вы очень усидчивы, тогда самоучитель. После изучения которого, принявшись за реальную практику, вы поймете, что почти ничего не знаете. Но зато что-то есть. А если вы уже знаете, как открывать браузер и выводить сообщение, то уже можно выполнять реальные проекты. Небольшие только.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. Самому мне 17. Планирую поступать на программиста и хочу идти туда уже с базовым знанием хотя бы чего-то. Просто (может я и ошибаюсь) мне кажется, что научный текст можно также сделать разнообразным и понятным. Может, есть библиотека конкретных примеров (целых программ) с комментариями?

Comment: Да множество таких примеров. Только толку от них??? Посмотрите и забудете. На этом конец. Большие программы на `JavaScript` - это искусство. Как ООП (объектно-ориентированное программирование). Я, например, некоторые интересные вещи делал, но уже не помню как. А то, что я подсмотрел - осталось в памяти как то, что это есть. Где-то.

Comment: понял. То есть советуете изучать по носорогу? Ладно, будем пробовать!

Comment: Да, не спешите, потихоничку вдумчиво, с перекурами, чтобы мозг сильно не взрывало ^^

Comment: @Vendetta8247 . Нет. Я хотел сказать, что в этой книге прекрасно описано много чего. А также хотел сказать, что скорее обучение будет проходить в реальной практике. +1 к @AlexWindHope . Сухое изучение учебника, по-моему, не очень правильное решение. Когда есть определенная задача, вы ищете как ее решить, а следовательно думаете и ищете литературу, какую угодно, и в итоге получаете больше знаний. При том закрепленных практикой. А по поводу книги, то там показан хороший стиль написания программ и объяснение процессов ... ... И если по-тихонечку, вдумчиво, то и как-то правильно, что-ли...

Answer (score 1):

Для меня лучшая книга:

> Beginning JavaScript Paul Wilton
> Jeremy McPeak Third Edition

От издательства Wrox

, у меня перевод этой книги

> Пол Вилтон Джереми МакПик Java Script
> Руководство программиста

от издательства Питер.
У меня эта книга. Я вам её очень советую и (особенно для дизайна) это самый лучший учебник imho

Answer (score 0):

Можно и отсюда - http://www.codecademy.com/ru/courses/javascript-beginner-jMOGH-ru

Правда тут уж все ну совсем просто, но если вы только начинаете - самое то.

Answer (score -1):

Как можно отговаривать от изучения JavaScript? Мол C++ или PHP лучше учи! На стороне клиента в браузере всегда исполняется JS, а не С и не ПХП. Хочешь, не хочешь, но учи JS! Браузер IE поддерживает еще бейсик-скрипт. При установленном ActivePerl в windows и perl браузером поддерживается, но JS везде, даже в PDF!

Comment: Кстати, можно и отговаривать, до некоторой степени. JS давно и резко теряет нишу «языка для web» и становится больше этаким «ассемблером/виртуальной машиной для web», в который только компилируют другие языки (CoffeeScript, Roy, HaXe, Amber).

Comment: давно и резко теряет нишу «языка для web»

Угу и в скором будущем JavaScript умрет xD

@drdaeman - если не разбираетесь в вопросе, то не несите ерунды. Каким на*** ассемблером? Я так понимаю вы серверный программист и о переменах в плане клиентской стороны знаете мало (вернее нифига не знаете xD), если так - зачем писать ерунду?

@welcomemyaltai - начинать с него все-же жестоко.

Comment: > Каким на*** ассемблером?

[Каким-то таким](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptIsAssemblyLanguageForTheWebPart2MadnessOrJustInsanity.aspx), например. Я ладно, я фронтэндов касаюсь редко и плохо, но умные дядьки типа Дугласа Крокфорда и Брендана Айка врать не будут, когда говорят «JS is the x86 of the web».

В последние пару лет, языков, компилируемых в JS, [как грибов после дождя полезло](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) и чаще и чаще слышны высказывания, что писать на, собственно, JS уже как-то некомильфо.

Comment: @drdaeman - жажду пруфа где Крокфорд говорит то что вы написали, до этого. Крокфорд фанат JavaScript'a, он этот язык любит и развивает и такого говорить не мог по определению.

У меня вообще складывается такое впечатления что все ваши мысли базируются на прочтении не авторитетных иностранных трололо-блогов (или вообще хз чего). Если это так - мне вас жалко.

Языков поверх JavaScript может быть хоть миллион, это ничего не меняет. Вообще если мыслить как вы C++ вообще никому не нужен уже лет 10 минимум, но почему-то это не так ;D

Comment: @AlexWindHope: Первая ссылка из комментария выше, на блог Скотта Хансельмана. Там переписка с Крокфордом и Айком, где они обсуждают [вот это](http://bit.ly/ntq0aI). Общая позиция — JS хорош как целевой-язык «ассемблер.» Что JS не нужен, или на нем не стоит писать, они, разумеется, не говорят.

Про некомильфо — это не Крокфорда утверждение, разумеется. Это мое мнение, на основе того, что я вижу (массовый уход на тот же CS), и такое же мнение встречал и во вполне приличных дискуссиях на том же Hacker News. От знания JS это не освобождает, но оно не приоритетно.

<troll>Да, и C++ не нужен</troll

Comment: @drdeaman - как вы можете адекватно рассуждать если вы толком не понимаете смысл языков которые реализованы поверх js?

То что JS хорош как база для другого языка я согласен, но извольте - разве это значит что теперь JavaScript не нужен и умрет?

Абсурд да и только.

По поводу "не приоритетно" - что-то мало я вижу вакансий с требованиями вида: "JS знать не надо, достаточно знать CoffeScript" и т.д. Везде первым требованием идет "pure" JavaScript, остальное лишь как плюс (и то далеко не везде)

Comment: Я такого не говорил. Как он может быть ненужным и умереть, если он используется как виртуальная машина? Не может такого быть. Но изучать, все же, стоит сначала языки высокого уровня или (в случае JS vs CS) с более приличным синтаксисом, а потом, когда будет время, копаться под капотом.

И вот программистов «знаю Dart или GWT, а в JS еле-еле разбираюсь» — я практически уверен — еще будет, дайте только вырасти всей этой свежей посадке. Мы это уже все прекрасно видели с умеющими делать сайты на Rails, но почти не знающими Ruby. И, нет, я не говорю все это, как что-то хоть каплю плохое — наоборот

Comment: Смысл копаться в том что сейчас никому не нужно (даже тебе самому)?
Ну да неважно, надоело спорить ниачем

Comment: @drdaeman и вы считаете JS низкоуровневым языком? (Ха! Ха! ХА!)