# Научиться JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui, ux

Здравствуй, сообщество (: 
Хочу изучить JavaScript, знаю несколько языков, имею огромный опыт веб-разработки, но до JS руки так и не дошли, постоянно брал откуда-то готовые примеры, никогда специфического ничего не требовалось. Но сейчас я хочу закрыть эту большую дыру и творить! (:

Мне не нужны начальные теоретические знания: циклы, условия, ооп и тому подобные конструкции - теорию я уже знаю. Я хочу *боевых* скринкастов / видеоуроков, мануалов, уроков или чего нибудь такого, где сразу без занудства будут описывать анимации, события, применение конкретных фреймворков - и их объектов и методов, или просто что нибудь красивое (:

В общем нужны пособия по UI / UX.
**Английский язык не проблема** - если есть что-нибудь стоящее - предлагайте! С удовольствием посмотрю / почитаю.

Заранее **огромное спасибо**!

*UPD: Прошло чуть меньше года, с момента как я задал этот вопрос, и я до сих пор изучаю все прелести JS. Тем, кто задаётся похожей целью, и тоже считает, что ему **не** нужны теоретические знания о JS - Вы, как и я раньше, ошибаетесь. JavaScript - прекраснейший язык, в нём много отличий от обычных ОО языков. Тут тебе и сплошь объекты, и прототипы, и события... В общем - начинайте с низов, и будет Вам счастье.*

Comment: Я не знаю какие Вы там языки знаете, но скорее всего Вы не в курсе, что наследование в JavaScript реализовано совсем не так, как в например в Java или C#. JavaScript только внешне похож на Си-подобные языки, на самом деле JS это функциональный язык и имеет больше общего с SmallTalk, Scheme и Lisp, чем с Java. Не ведитесь на название и мнимую простоту синтаксиса. Лучше посмотрите исходники библиотеки prototype.js или jquery.

Comment: Поэтому советую начинать с самых основ, например с оператора запятая. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Мне не нужны начальные теоретические знания

"JavaScript Шаблоны" уже рекомендовали так что:

- **JavaScript Web Applications**
- **[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)**

прочее:

- [Что почитать, чтобы повысить свой уровень JavaScript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117838/)
- [ECMA-262-3 in detail](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/tag/ecma-262-3/)
- [wtfjs](http://wtfjs.com/)

---

> по UI / UX.

- [Ководство](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/)
- Психбольница в руках пациентов

Comment: Ништяк, спасибо (:

Answer (score 3):

Привет.
Можете почитать следующие книги: Стоян Стефанов "JavaScript Шаблоны", шаблоны программирования и проектирования высококачественных приложений, а также книга Джона
Рейсига "JavaScript Профессиональные приемы программирования".
**UPD** Также книга Дэвида Флэнагана "JavaScript Подробное руководство", но Вам ее не всю можно читать, начало можете пропустить, т.к. там основы, однако в конце первой части книги и вся вторая часть книгипосвящена многим интересным вопросам программирования на JavaScript, например разработка сценариев для Java - приложений, JavaScript и XML, работа с графикой на стороне клиента.

Comment: Там больше того, чего мне не нужно, чем нужно )
Но всё равно большое спасибо, книги хорошие.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю более забавный и интересный способ.
[codeacademy.com](http://codeacademy.com)

---

Заодно и английский язык потренируете. Это довольно интересный способ обучения. 
Но ни в коем случае не спорю, книги и практика это первейший источник обучения.

Comment: Курс прошёл там, штука хорошая (:
Оттуда-то и знаю основы. Но мне нужно немного другое.

Answer (score 2):

Как я уже говорил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44594/javascript-c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-js?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=148072#148072)

Для меня лучшая книга:

```
Beginning JavaScript Paul Wilton Jeremy McPeak Third Edition
```

От издательства Wrox

, у меня перевод этой книги

```
Пол Вилтон Джереми МакПик Java Script Руководство программиста
```

от издательства Питер.
У меня эта книга. Я вам её очень советую и (особенно для дизайна) это самый лучший учебник imho