# С чего начать javascript?

Tags: javascript, книги

Всем доброго времени суток. Я начинающий веб-мастер, хочу стать действительно серьёзным специалистом. начал изучение этой сферы занятий с изучения HTML, потом CSS, после немного интересовался SEO, пытался начать осваивать PHP(ну самые азы и то тяжело дались), решил отложить php, поюзал фотошоп (ну самое основное, типо работы с макетами, как рисовать самые простенькие макеты и т.д.), вот теперь хочу заняться **javascript(ом)**. И вот тут прошу вашей помощи.

1. Подскажите, с чего бы начать? Я пока нашёл несколько текстовых учебников, но они какие-то непонятные. На ютубе нарыл уроки Андрея Морковина (и вроде они ничего такие). А может кто-то из вас ещё что-то интересное посоветует.
2. Для HTML/CSS есть прекрасный сайт [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/), на котором можно указать любой тег или что-то потипу, свойство селекторов и т.д. и получить по нему информацию.
   Для php сайт [php.ru](http://www.php.ru/manual/), который в принципе является справочником, а есть ли что-то похожее для <b>javascript</b>?

Comment: [Д. Флэнаган - JavaScript][1]. Лучше книги по JS не видел.


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3881091/

Comment: Для JS есть гугл, который в первых строках выдачи выдает ссылку, например, на такое: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [javascript - учебник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63304/javascript-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18105/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут отвечали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63304/javascript-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Добавлю. [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/) Удобный справочник по множеству объектов, используемых в web. По поводу html+cs+js также дается информация о поддержке браузерами. Полно туториалов...

upd про w3schools по первой ссылке уже советовали...

Answer (score 5):

Хочешь стать профи? Реально? Так вот открою тебе 1 секрет, профи учат материал по ночам и дням, не вылазя из-за компов тестируют строчки кода, чтобы досконально разобраться в каком-либо языке.Эти люди не бросают материал и не переходят к другому делу, пока с ним не разберутся.Речь идёт об упорстве, о любопытстве, о настоящем любопытстве и любви к своему делу.Ты действительно упорный человек?Ты готов ЧЕРЕЗ СИЛУ сидеть и разбираться, когда тебе надоело учить и кодить, но надо это делать?Ответь себе на мои вопросы.Если ты сомневаешься хоть в каком ответе - займись чем-либо другим, ты не станешь профи, ты до средне-скиловых не дойдёшь.Все кричат что хотят стать профи, а на деле 0.Читайте эту заметку перед тем как начать программировать.

А по сабжу: обратись к Дэвиду Флэнагану Руководоство по JavaScript, всего 600 страниц.Недели на отличное изучение хватит.Время пошло...

Comment: Ну может на всевозможных форумах и подобных этому ресурсу многие с подобными фразами Вас достали(чему я сочувствую), ну просто я по образованию гуманитарий(историк). И Если HTML и CSS в принципе не вызвали у меня трудностей, то освоение php для меня стало тяжеловато, я проконсультировался с людьми которые так или иначе связанны с web технологиями и получил советы. 1)Попробовать начать учить программирование с языка C. 2) Отложить php и изучать javascript. Мол начал с вёрстки ей и учись, а потом уже лезь в другие процессы.

PS Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Нет разницы кто Вы ) Есть разница как Вы подойдёте к делу, я об этом.Я вас сразу настраиваю что будет нелегко.Могу сказать что Вам правильно посоветовали, ещё добавлю, выучите это аккуратно!Всего доброго без обид ;)